# Destroy data based on HTML class name in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a simple todo list using Rails (3.2.5).

I show all of the users todo items in an unordered list, each list item being the todo itself. By clicking on the todo item the user marks it as completed. Using jQuery I give the li a class of done so I can change its styling. By clicking on a "Clear completed" button I want the completed items to be destroyed (and deleted from the database).

How can this be done?

NB: I'm basically trying to recreate this app using Rails: http://davidpdrsn.com/todos/

Comment: So why don't you look how he did it?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the model is called `Todo` and the completed column is called `completed`, you can write one of these in the controller:

```
Todo.destroy_all(:completed => true)
Todo.where(:completed => true).destroy_all
```

If you need help with how to manage the ajax request/response, [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec%3aa_working_follow_button_with_ajax) there is a good start (sorry, I don't want to give you the solution, IMHO you should make your way by yourself)

Resources: [ActiveRecord#Base::destroy_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all)

Comment: I'd make a custom controller action that responds to js which updates the db then runs the jquery to update the view

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev Sorry but the solution is simple, and there are a lot of resources about this argument out there (railstutorial, railsforzombies, etc); IMHO it is important that he finds this solution by himself in order to get better

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a remote form
So you would have something like

you would have a form with `remote: true` for each item or you could have only one form and submit it with JQuery.

```
class TodoController
  def set_completed
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @todo.done = true  # you could move this to your model and do something like @todo.done! and that would save it automatically
    @todo.save
  end

  def  destroy_completed 
    @todos_to_delete = Todo.where(done: true)# here you could also move it to your model and do it like Todo.completed
    @todos_to_delete.destroy_all
  end
end
```

and you would render the response with the js for formatting, or even removing items on your list, like

views/todo/set_completed.erb.js

```
$("#item_<%= @todo.id %>").addClass("completed");
```